# react js jquery load script keyword not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, charts

I am following this tutorial: https://blog.arkency.com/2014/09/react-dot-js-and-google-charts/

I am not able to load google charts for ReactJS. I am trying to load it with jQuery.

I get following compile error:

> 'google' is not defined

However my console.log statement is able to access 'google' keyword.

```
console.log('google',google, script, textStatus)
```

> google {loader: {…}, load: ƒ, ca: ƒ, setOnLoadCallback: ƒ} undefined success

My code is following:

```
var options = {
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    url: "https://www.google.com/jsapi"
};

jQuery.ajax(options).done(loadGoogle)



function loadGoogle(script, textStatus){

    console.log('google',google, script, textStatus)

    google.load("visualization", "1", {
            packages:["corechart"],
            callback: renderComponents()
        }
    )

}
```

Comment: Does `renderComponents` return function? if no then remove `()`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `window.google` or add this line on top of all the import `/* global google */`